# VBA Problems with resizing an array in a struct (Type)

Tags: vba, types

For a project of mine in VBA, I need to have a custom type like this:

```
Public Type Gene
  Name As String 
  Expression() As Double             'holds data points, is a vector
  Norm_Expression() As Double        'Holds normalized data, is a vector
  Min_Corr As Double
  Min_Profile As Integer 
End Type
```

But I'm finding it difficult to change the size of the the inner arrays by a redim statement.

```
ReDim Data(n)
For i = 1 To n
   ReDim Preserve Data.Expression(Max_Time_Point)
Next i
```

Does not work. Neither does:

```
For i = 1 To n
    ReDim Data(n).Expression(Max_Time_Point)Does not work. Neither does:
Next i
```

Could you help? Thank you!

Comment: @tim williams invalid qualifier

Answer (score 1):

Almost there - you need to indicate which member of `Data` you want to work on:

```
For i = 1 To n
   ReDim Preserve Data(i).Expression(Max_Time_Point)
Next i
```

Note when you do this

```
ReDim Data(n)
```

it's the same as `ReDim Data(0 to n)` so in your loop if you start at 1 you miss the first element.